# Data Nodes not Appearing in Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create a hadoop cluster. `hdfs' is starting normally and I am lso able to access it through the web interface. But, data nodes are not showing. Here is the result I got by running jps command.
[image: jps command result]

`node1` is the `master-node`. But running `yarn node -list' is not returning the list of worker nodes.
[image: yarn node -list result]

hdfs and yarn seem to have started normally. Here is the response from `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.

[image]

What should I do?

Here is the xml file for `yarn-site.xml`. The memory for the nodes is 2GB each.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>                
        <value>node1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
    <!-- Resource-->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>1536</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>1536</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to restart services using `stop-all.sh` then restarted them. Any advice?

Comment: HDFS is not "starting normally" if there are no datanodes. `yarn-site.xml` has nothing to do with DataNodes. You need to run `start-dfs.sh`, then show us any errors from the **datanode logs**. Similarly, `start-yarn.sh` should start **NodeManagers**, and those also have logs you should look at for errors.

Comment: I have added the outputs from `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`. Thanks

Comment: I asked for actual process logs, please, not the command output. There are log files written to the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the `yarn-site.xml` file. I should have added the resource manager address. If node1 is the name of the master node, then:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>                
    <value>node1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>node1:8032</value>
</property>
```